# How to determine input as a floating point number and/or integer within a loop?

Tags: python, loops, floating-point, integer

How can I determine whether user input is EITHER a `float` or an `integer` within a loop? If they input something other than `integer`/`float`, I want the loop to repeat until they correctly input a `float`/`integer`.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: "while userInputNotSatisfied:" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python

Answer (score -1):

You can use Errors that are being reported when trying to parse incorrect data using float() and int() function.First, define a generic function to parse both int and float and throw some exception in all other cases:

```
def parse(x):
    value=0
    try:
        value = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            value = float(x)
        except ValueError:
            raise Exception
    return value
```

you can use this generic function to determine correct or incorrect input in a loop

```
correct = False
while not correct:
    try:
        parse(input("Enter data:"))
        correct = True
    except Exception:
        print("Invalid input...enter again!")
```